# How to convert CGPDFPageRef into NSData xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I did not convert a `CGPDFPageRef` into `NSData`. I  want to cut PDF into pages. And want to view it into a webview. Here is my code:

```
    CGPDFPageRef page=CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf,1);

    CGRect mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    // output
    CGDataConsumerRef consumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(*outputData);
    CGContextRef context = CGPDFContextCreate(consumer, &mediaBox, NULL);
    // draw
    CGContextBeginPage(context, &mediaBox);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
    CGContextEndPage(context);

    // This line gives me an error:

    NSData *passDat = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)outputData;
```

Comment: I want to load CGPDFPageRef into a UIWebView.So, for loading a pdf page at webview i need NSData.That's why my question how can i convert CFData into NSData at Xcode 7 arc?

Comment: it gives ERROR :Incompatible type casting CFDataRef *(aka *const struct __CFData **) to NSData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert CFData to NSData, you can do this:

```
NSData *passDat = (__bridge NSData *)outputData;
```

Make sure you define the `outputData` without the `*`.

```
CFDataRef outputData;
```

> CFData is “toll-free bridged” with its Cocoa Foundation counterpart, NSData. What this means is that the Core Foundation type is interchangeable in function or method calls with the bridged Foundation object.

[CFDataRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDataRef/)

---

**Loading an entire PDF**

If your intention is to load the entire PDF into a UIWebView and just view it there, you can do the following:

```
// create an url to the PDF    
let url = NSURL(string: "file://some/path/my.pdf")

// you can optionally append #page[pageNumber] to the url string to make the UIWebView display a desired page;
// NSURL(string: "file://some/path/my.pdf#page45")

// create a request with the provided url
let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

// load the PDF file into the UIWebView
webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
```

Comment: I want to load CGPDFPageRef into a UIWebView.So, for loading a pdf page at webview i need NSData.That's why my question how can i convert CFData into NSData at Xcode 7 arc

Comment: it gives ERROR :Incompatible type casting CFDataRef *(aka *const struct __CFData **) to NSData